# How to integrate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^ne^{x-x^2} dx$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I am trying to integrate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^ne^{x-x^2} dx$ for n = 0,1,2 but I can't think of how to do this for any n.

I managed (I believe) to show that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xe^{x-x^2} dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{x-x^2}dx$ and similarly that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2e^{x-x^2} dx = \frac{3}{4}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{x-x^2}dx$.

This means I only need to do the integral for one n, but I can't see which or how.

If anyone could put me on the right track it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT:

Let $F(a)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ax-x^2}\,dx=\sqrt\pi e^{a^2/4}$.  Then, we have

$$\left.\left(\frac{d^nF(a)}{da^n}\right)\right|_{a=1}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^n e^{x-x^2}\,dx$$

Comment: Thanks, but I'm a bit confused about where you got the first result from. Is that to do with the gaussian integral?

Comment: You're welcome.  Yes, complete the square on $ax-x^2$.

Comment: @user3047368. Complete the square and change variable to get the first and key result.

Comment: Hi Mark ! Good answer as usual. Cheers :-)

Comment: @MarkViola Ah, of course. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Hello Claude my friend.  How are you?